# how to add '-include global.h' after '-I includedir'?

Tags: waf

I'm trying to use -include preprocessor option. [GCC Preprocessor Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)
I've failed to do that in my configure method as regular CXXFLAGS option

```
def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_cxx')
    conf.env.append_value('CXXFLAGS', ['-g', '-include global.h'])
```

due to it add's it before `-I` options. And gcc could not find my header. How I can add `-include global.h` after all `-I` options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:

```
def build(bld):
    bld.env.MYFLAGS = ['-include', 'global.h']
    from waflib import Task
    class cxx(Task.classes['cxx']):
        run_str = '${CXX} ${ARCH_ST:ARCH} ${CXXFLAGS}${FRAMEWORKPATH_ST:FRAMEWORKPATH} ${FRAMEWORK_ST:FRAMEWORK}${CPPPATH_ST:INCPATHS} ${MYFLAGS} ${DEFINES_ST:DEFINES}${CXX_SRC_F}${SRC} ${CXX_TGT_F}${TGT}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can look at the waf book § 10.3.2. You can attach a specific method to the cxx feature in order to add the '-include' option after the include paths.

Another way is to monkeypatch the cxx class and modify the run_str string that manage the comilation.

Third option : Ask on waf mailing list, you usually get an answer very quickly ^^